# Custom domain redirects to Heroku domain instead of acting as alias

Tags: heroku, dns

I've tried connecting my Heroku app to a custom domain. When I go to my custom domain a redirect happens but the url then appears as "{name}.herokuapp.com". I bought the domain from Hover and have added both www.{domain}.com and {domain}.com to Heroku. Output of `heroku domains` shown here:

[image]

I then added both targets to Hover (shown here):
[image]

I'm quite confused and any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to Hover customer support I found out that aliasing with Heroku isn't possible. They offer redirects but that's it. They need an IP address to use as an A name but Heroku changes your IP address regularly so it's not possible. I'm moving it to NameCheap and using that instead.